# rCharts for some functions such as timeline in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, interactive, rcharts

I am using rCharts in shiny app.  rCharts is a very useful package for visualization. when we move mouse above the figure ,then it will hint me some messege. for example, i have a dataframe like !data.frame(date=c(....),revenue=c(....))

then when make it into a plot , when mouse moved on  it will tell us the date and the revenue,

but I want change this message such as when mouse point to it ,it will tell me what happend in that
day ,
so i can change the dataframe like this :data.frame(date=c(....),revenue=c(....),events=c(...))

if it is comes ture ,it will be very easy to check what events have happend to influence my revenue. if any body knows how to realize it ,please tell me! thanks.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you are having. rCharts has many underlying charting libraries please also indicate which in particular you are using.

Comment: ah,just want a simple chart like http://glimmer.rstudio.com/pssguy/CRANcountdown/     but i want when mouse over the point, it will tell me what happend at this point. I mean how to change the default label of the point. thanks for your answer.

Comment: either hightcharts ,or nvd3,or morris  is ok

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to adjust the tooltip to display the `events` column.

Here's an example where I want to plot the `disp` column against the `hp` column, but the tooltip hover should display the `gear` column.

```
n<-nPlot(disp~hp,data=mtcars,type='lineChart')
n$chart(
  tooltipContent="#! function(key, x, y, e){
  return  e.point.gear
} !#"
  )
```

You can add whatever html you want to the `tooltipContent` to format things to your liking.

Comment: thanks , it's works well. but can you tell me what should I do in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584878/label-above-points-with-rchart-failed-with-chinese

Comment: Sure. If this answer if sufficient, please close the question.